# Storing the value

Tags: python

Is it possible to store a value obtained from a definition into a variable?

```
def desks_for_group(x):
    students_per_desk = 2

    if x % 2 == 0:
        x = x
    else:
        x += 1

    desks = x / students_per_desk
    print(desks)

group_1 = int(input())
group_2 = int(input())
group_3 = int(input())

total_desks_required = (desks_for_group(group_1) + desks_for_group(group_2) + 
desks_for_group(group_3))

print(total_desks_required)
```

Comment: I need to use the value obtained from the definition into another equation, is it possible?

Comment: Just simply return the value you want from the function?

Answer (score 0):

Use `return`.

After all the computation is done return sends the value back to the function call.
Read more on return [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_return.asp).

If you want to store that value as a variable assign the function call to the variable, like this:

```
var=my_function(arg1,arg1)
```

This will store the computed value into var.

Here, you can store two or more returned values using:

```
var1, var2 = my_function(arg1,arg2)
```

In your case this works like:

```
def desks_for_group(x):
    students_per_desk = 2

    if x % 2 == 0:
        x = x
    else:
        x += 1

    desks = x / students_per_desk
    return desks

group_1 = int(input())
group_2 = int(input())
group_3 = int(input())

total_desks_required = (desks_for_group(group_1) + desks_for_group(group_2) + 
desks_for_group(group_3))

print(total_desks_required)
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked